# 1.82 meters between 2 lat readings -- What would that be in minutes?

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude

If I have 2 longitudes that are seperated by 1.82 meters how would I estimate their separation in minutes?

Here is what I did not sure if it is valid

```
X   Y
52.33816424 -106.2851684
52.33816424 -106.2851419
```

2 points  representing the center of 2 plots so to get the width of a plot I find the difference between the centers:

```
abs(-106.2851684) - abs(-106.2851419) = 0.000026500000004
```

so

```
1/2plot = 0.000026500000004/2 = 0.000013250000002
```

so top of plot 1 =-106.2851684  - 0.000013250000002 = -106.285181650000000

does that make sense?

I know minutes isn't a distance measure.

Comment: There's no guarantee that common boundary is equidistant between the two plot centers.

Comment: Project the points to a coordinate system in metres, based on your coords perhaps WGS84 UTM Zone 13 North (EPSG:32613 http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-13n/) provided your lat/lon are in WGS84 then get the distance using Pythagorean formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem. Or you could use Geodesic Distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory) - much harder maths but more accurate. Given your coords are to 8 decimal (but are they accurate to 8 decimals?) Geodesic accuracy might be warranted but will not make much difference over < 2m.

Comment: Note: **your X and Y are the wrong way around** coords in geographic are X -180 to 180, Y -90 to 90; a Y of -106 is outside that domain so your **coordinates must be flipped**.

Comment: yes sorry the XY is setup that way to plot in google maps. Thanks Micheal that seems fairly complicated I wished I had paid attention in here http://www.engr.usask.ca/classes/CE/316/notes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you already have lat/long values in degrees, and the two points are at the same latitude. So if you want to know the angle between your two points, all you need is the difference between the longitudes:

```
abs(-106.2851684 -(-106.2851419)) = 0.000026500000004 degrees
```

then convert the degrees in minutes:

```
0.000026500000004*60 = 0.00159 minutes
```

For a quick conversion in meters, the size of a parallel at a given latitude is equal to, approximately (assuming that the Earth is a sphere),

```
2*pi()*6370 km * cos(lat)
```

so in your case,

```
distance = 2*pi()*6370000 * cos(52.33816424) * 0.000026500000004 / 360 = 1.8 m
```

this can be inverted to get the angle in degrees if you know the latitude and the distance in meters

```
   angle = distance *360 / (2*pi()*6370000*cos(lat))
```

If you are not at the same latitude, use the dot product to get the angle A between them:

```
so cos(A)= sin(lat1)sin(lat2)+ cos(lat1)cos(lat2)cos{long1-long2}
```

This is based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231221/great-arc-distance-between-two-points-on-a-unit-sphere/231225#231225 knowing that cos(pi/2-x) = sin(x) and sin(pi/2-x)= cos(x).

For the final result, take the inverse of cos(A) in degree and multiply it by 60 to get the minutes.

As a remark, if the plots are adjacent, the distance between their centers is equal to their average width in the direction of the line that joins their centers (in other words, don't take the half of it)